# Warning about arithmetic overflow when multiplying numbers

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program to calculate the result of numbers:

```
int main()
{
    float a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    float result = b + a * a * 0.4;
    cout << result;
}
```

but I have a warning at `a * a` and it said `Warning C26451 Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2).` Sorry if this a newbie question, can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: This is just a harmless warning. Fix it by writing `float result = b + a * a * 0.5f;` (note the f suffix).

Comment: @prapin there do exist `float`s such that `a * a` will lose precision.  The result will be approximated in ways that `double` could avoid.  [example](https://godbolt.org/z/fx7373Y6x)

Comment: Make it `double result = b + a * a * 0.4f;` warning telling you that result can be larger then maximal value float can take.

Comment: @VictorGubin I do not think your suggestion will work as described.  Converting the final result from `float` to `double` will not produce a more accurate result.  The same loss of precision occurs.

Answer (score 1):

In the C language as described in the first edition of K&R, all floating-point operations were performed by converting operands to a common type (specifically `double`), performing operations with that type, and then if necessary converting the result to whatever type was needed.  On many platforms, that was the most convenient and space-efficient way of handling floating-point math.  While the Standard still allows implementations to behave that way, it also allows implementations to perform floating-point operations on smaller types to be performed using those types directly.

As written, the subexpression `a * a * 0.5;` would be performed by multiplying `a * a` together using `float` type, then multiply by a value 0.5 which is of type `double`.  This latter multiplication would require converting the `float` result of `a * a` to double.  If e.g. `a` had been equal to 2E19f, then performing the multiply using type `float` would yield a value too large to be represented using that type.  Had the code instead performed the multiplication using type `double`, then the result 4E38 would be representable in that type, and the result of multiplying that by 0.5 (i.e. 2E38) would be within the range that is representable by `float`.

Note that in this particular situation, the use of `float` for the intermediate computations would only affect the result if `a` was within narrow ranges of very large or very small.  If instead of multiplying by 0.5 one had multiplied by other values, however, the choice of whether to use `float` or `double` for the first multiplication could affect the accuracy of rounding.  Generally, using `double` for both multiplies would yield slightly more accurate results, but at the expense of increased execution time.  Using `float` for both may yield better execution speed, but at the result of reduced precision.  If the floating-point constant had been something that isn't precisely representable in `float`, converting to `double` and multiplying by a `double` constant may yield slightly more accurate results than using `float` for everything, but in most cases where one would want that precision, one would also want the increased position that would be achieved by using `double` for the first multiply as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the error message.

> Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value

It is describing this code:

```
a * a
```

Your `float` is 4 bytes.  The result of the multiplication is 4 bytes.  And the result of a multiplication may overflow.

> and then casting the result to a 8 byte value.

It is describing this code:

```
(result) * 0.4;
```

Your result is 4 bytes.  `0.4` is a `double`, which is 8 bytes.  C++ will promote your `float` result to a `double` before performing this multiplication.

**So...**

The compiler is observing that you are doing `float` math that could overflow and then immediately converting the result to a `double`, making the potential overflow unnecessary.

Change the code to this to remove the `float` to `double` to `float` conversions.

```
float result = b + a * a * 0.4f;
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the question as "how to change the code to remove the warning?".

If you take the advice in the warning's text literally:

```
float result = b + (double)a * a * 0.4;
```

But this is nonsense — if an overflow happens, your result will probably not fit into `float result`.

It looks like in your case overflow is not possible, and you feel perfectly fine doing all calculations with `float`. If so, just write `0.4f` instead of `0.4` — then the constant will have `float` type (instead of `double`), and the result will also be `float`.

If you want to "fix" the problem with overflow

```
double result = b + (double)a * a * 0.4;
```

But then you must also change the following code, which uses the `result`. And you don't remove the possibility of overflow, you just make it much less likely.